# Eclipse - Using different colors for printing

Tags: eclipse, printing

I am using the [Obsidian theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=21) with the [Eclipse Color Theme plugin](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin).

When coding I am very happy with how everything looks:

[image: Obsidian on screen]

However, printed code is rather hard to read:

[image: Obsidian print out]

Is there any way to make Eclipse print with different colors than it displays?

Comment: Tell your printer to print in black and white, (without shades of grey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a quick and dirty answer... change theme prior to printing.

Comment: another quick and dirty answer: don't print code, save the trees.

Comment: @hexa Ah, but notice the above screenshot is from a pdf printer.

Answer (score 4):

2 1/2 yrs later, for others besides OP :) Right click your file in Project Explorer and choose 'Open with'; choose Text editor instead of Java/etc editor and print from there. Or alternatively, System Editor (if yours lets you check/uncheck 'print syntax highlighting'). Unless you can force your printer to use black & white instead of grayscale. I couldn't.

Comment: perfect solution to this problem!